# SQL Oracle - Prorated values from date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in SQL oracle and their dates in strings. The Contract Value of each customer should be prorated across the date range and then annualized to calculate the annual price increases.

[image]

What my query should return is:

[image]

As for customer A, no proration is needed since both contracts run for a whole year. Customer B will need proration as its Contract Values fall across different years. To get to customer B's 2021 annual value, $100 needs to be divided by the contracted months (6) and then annualized (*12 months). How to account for these scenarios in my query?

Comment: **NEVER** store dates as strings (and especially not if you are not going to be using ISO8601 formatted strings). Alter the table and store them as dates.

Answer (score 2):

If the contract value is spread evenly over every day between the start- and end-dates and then you can split the contracts on the year boundaries and work out the number of days for each part of the contract and the fractional value for each year and then total the part contract values as the annual contract rate and compare:

```sql
WITH split_years (customer, product, year, days, contract_days, contract_value) AS (
  SELECT customer,
         product,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM year_start),
         (LEAST(year_end, contract_end + 1) - GREATEST(year_start, contract_start)),
         contract_end + 1 - contract_start,
         contract_value
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
           SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(contract_start, 'YY'), 12 * (LEVEL - 1)) AS year_start,
                  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(contract_start, 'YY'), 12 * LEVEL) AS year_end
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY
                  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(contract_start, 'YY'), 12 * (LEVEL - 1)) < contract_end
         )
),
year_averages (customer, product, year, total_contract_value) AS (
  SELECT customer,
         product,
         year,
         ROUND(SUM(contract_value * days / contract_days), 2)
  FROM   split_years
  GROUP BY
         customer,
         product,
         year
)
SELECT customer,
       product,
       contract_value_2021,
       contract_value_2022,
       (contract_value_2022 / contract_value_2021 - 1) * 100 AS percent_increase
FROM   year_averages
PIVOT (
  MAX(total_contract_value)
  FOR year IN (
    2021 AS contract_value_2021,
    2022 AS contract_value_2022
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (customer, product, contract_value, contract_start, contract_end) AS
SELECT 'A', 1,  150, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1,  160, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1,  100, DATE '2021-09-13', DATE '2022-03-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1,  120, DATE '2022-03-13', DATE '2022-09-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1,  300, DATE '2022-09-13', DATE '2023-09-12' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: **NEVER** store dates as strings. If you must (don't) then you will need to convert the strings to dates in the query using `TO_DATE`.*

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER | PRODUCT | CONTRACT_VALUE_2021 | CONTRACT_VALUE_2022 | PERCENT_INCREASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 150 | 160 | 6.666666666666666666666666666666666667 |
| B | 1 | 60.77 | 249.64 | 310.794800065821951620865558663814382096 |

---

#### Previous answer:

Assuming that each contract is for a year and you are working out a day-rate then you can split the contracts on the year boundaries, then work out the number of days for each part of the contract and the day-rate for the contract and then you can work out the weighted average as the annual contract rate and compare:

```sql
WITH split_years (customer, product, year, days, year_days, day_rate) AS (
  SELECT customer,
         product,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM year_start),
         (LEAST(year_end, contract_end + 1) - GREATEST(year_start, contract_start)),
         year_end - year_start,
         contract_value / (year_end - year_start)
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
           SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(contract_start, 'YY'), 12 * (LEVEL - 1)) AS year_start,
                  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(contract_start, 'YY'), 12 * LEVEL) AS year_end
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY
                  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(contract_start, 'YY'), 12 * (LEVEL - 1)) < contract_end
         )
),
year_averages (customer, product, year, avg_contract_value) AS (
  SELECT customer,
         product,
         year,
         ROUND(SUM(day_rate * days)/SUM(days)*MAX(year_days), 2)
  FROM   split_years
  GROUP BY
         customer,
         product,
         year
)
SELECT customer,
       product,
       contract_value_2021,
       contract_value_2022,
       (contract_value_2022 / contract_value_2021 - 1) * 100 AS percent_increase
FROM   year_averages
PIVOT (
  MAX(avg_contract_value)
  FOR year IN (
    2021 AS contract_value_2021,
    2022 AS contract_value_2022
  )
)
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER | PRODUCT | CONTRACT_VALUE_2021 | CONTRACT_VALUE_2022 | PERCENT_INCREASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 150 | 160 | 6.666666666666666666666666666666666667 |
| B | 1 | 100 | 170.36 | 70.36 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xoAwhdzM)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your query ends up having a different 2022 value for Customer B. How could I edit this calc to get to the value of 245 (100/6*3+120+300/12*3)?

Comment: @Es-Dot Updated - however, your values are not accurate as `2021-09-13` to `2022-01-01` is less than 3 months and `2022-01-01` to `2022-03-13` is more than 3 months and  `2022-09-13` to `2023-01-01` is less than 3 months.